# Extend logback provider configuration

Tags: java, logstash, logback, slf4j

I have a default appender configuration (which uses providers from logstash-logback-encoder) similar to the one below

```
<appender name="JSON_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
 <encoder class="a.b.c.logging.CustomLogbackEncoder">
  <providers>
   <timestamp/>
   <version/>
   <loggerName/>
   <threadName/>
   <logLevel/>
   <provider class="a.b.c.logging.LogMaskingProvider">
    <rules>
     <rule>
      <name>cc</name>
      <pattern>\d{13,18}</pattern>
     </rule>
    <rule>
      <name>SSN</name>
      <pattern>\s+\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}\s+</pattern>
    </rule>
   </rules>
   <userRules>
    <!-- **** Read custom user rules ****--->
    </userRules>
   </provider>
   <stackTrace/>
  </providers>
 </encoder>
</appender>
```

The above config is read and configured using the ImplicitAction without any issue and binds to the following POJO

```
public class Rules {

  private final Set<Rule> rules = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  public void addRule(Rule definition) {
   rules.add(definition.createRule());
 }
...
}
```

acts as a default configuration. This default configuration is not directly available to the clients, so they can't directly make changes to it.

I am looking for ways to extend this default configuration where in the different users can specify additional rules in . This configuration is provided in separate file outside of logback.xml in a file called custom.xml something like

```
<userRules>   
 <rule>
  <name>email</name>
  <pattern>([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}</pattern>
 </rule>
 <rule>
   ...
 </rule>
</userRules>
```

I am looking for help to implement this (marked between ****)  so as that the provider gets the userRules as provided in the external file and the log back appender is configured with the set of default + custom rules

Any pointers around how to implement this will be helpful